# Rendering mongodb database results from POST request in .ajax jquery wrapper in node js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb

I am creating a basic piece of functionality to allow users to send their location to a server which then queries a database and returns locations near to them. I am using the below jQuery .ajax wrapper to POST data to the server. This takes the form of a latlon point which is then used as the basis for a geosearch in MongoDB using nodejs and express on the backend. The results of the search are then intended to be returned to the client and rendered by the createMapListings function.

The /find page is initially rendered through a GET request to the database via mongodb separate from the below code. However subsequent to initial rendering, I then want to return results dependent on the location provided.

The POST method works fine and the location is posted to the server, with the search results being returned as I can print contents out through the console log.

However, I then want to render the results on the client-side. As mentioned, the results of the search render in the console, but when I attempt to pass through to the client, I can render the data itself (in the form of an array of objects) in the #output div, but the createMapListings function does not seem to catch the data.

In fact, the below function appears to be called but prints out over a thousand rows with the data that should be caught described as 'undefined'. I have tried to use res.render and res.redirect, but in the first case, the view renders in the div (which I suppose is expected) and the redirect fails.

The createMapListings function works fine when a simple GET request is made to the server, for example, for all objects in a collection, using ejs template. However, I think the issue here may be a combination of a POST request and then wanting to pass the results back to the AJAX request using the complete callback.

I apologise if the below code is somewhat obtuse. I’m definitely what you would call a beginner. I appreciate the above functionality may not possible so if there is a better way, I would of course be open to it (res.direct perhaps).

Here is the relevant client side script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#geolocate").click(function(){ 
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocate, function(){

        });
     });
 });

function geolocate(pos){
     var latlonpt = [];
     var x = pos.coords.latitude;
     var y = pos.coords.longitude;
     latlonpt.push(x);
     latlonpt.push(y); 

    var obj = {
    userlocation: latitudelongitudept
    };

   $.ajax({
    url: "/find",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    processData: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(obj),
    complete: function (data) {
        $('#output').html(data.responseText);
        $('#infooutput').children().remove();
        createMapListings(data.responseText); 
        }
     });
 };


 function createMapListings(maps) {
 for (var i = 0; i < maps.length; i++) {
 var url = maps[i]._id;
 var fullurl = "<a href='/show?id=" + url + "'>Route</a></div>";
 var title = "<div>" + maps[i].title + " - " + fullurl +"";
 $('#infooutput').append(title);

     };
  };

 </script>
```

Here is the relevant route used in a basic express app to handle the post request made by the above .ajax wrapper.

```
 exports.findbylocation = function(req, res) {
 console.log(req.body.userlocation);
 var userlocation = req.body.userlocation;
 Map.ensureIndexes;
 Map.find({loc :{ $near : userlocation }}, function(err, maps) {

 if (err) { 
          console.log(err)
          }
 else {    
       var jmaps = JSON.stringify(maps);
       console.log(jmaps);
       res.send(jmaps);
      }      
   });
};
```

Comment: are u getting back data from node.js when doing the ajax on `/post`? Where is the problem? in jQuery displaying the JSON or in node/mongodb doing the query?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am able to do a simple res.send of the data which displays the data in the #output div on the client side. The problem therefore to me appears to be that the related function is not able to read the object on the client side in terms of iterating over the data to read out the various elements contained in the function.

Comment: Are you sure that `data.responseText` in the Ajax function is a JSON format and not a string. If not not you'll have to parse it in order for `createMapListings()` to open the `maps` object and get the `_id` and `title`. - Put `console.log()` inside both functions and check the output in the browser console (Developer Tools in Chrome)

Comment: You're right - I suspect data.responseText is incorrect or at least is a string which requires further attention. Thank you for helping me narrow this down. Will investigate further. Although yes, the intention is to send the JSON object through for parsing by the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By convention, the `data` variable name in an `$.ajax` callback signature refers to the parsed HTTP response body. Since your callback is on `complete`, we're actually passed the  `XMLHttpRequest` used, by convention called `xhr`. You rightly grab the `responseText` property, but this needs parsing to be useful. So long as we take care over our `Content-Type`'s and don't explicitly disable `processData`, jQuery will do the encoding/unencoding  for us - we just deal with objects. This is a good thing, since the transport format isn't usually of any particular importance to the application logic. If we use `res.json(maps)` in place of `res.send(jmaps)`, we can write our call more simply:

```
$.ajax({
    url:  '/find',
    type: 'POST',
    data: obj,

    success: function(data) {},
    error:   function(xhr, text, err) {}
});
```

Here `data` is a Javascript object already parsed and ready to use. We also use a default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request rather than explicitly setting a `contentType`. This is the same as far as express is concerned: it will just be parsed by [urlencoded](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/urlencoded.html) instead of [json](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/json.html).

Comment: Worked like a charm. I think I need to work harder to better understand the various options that go into the ajax function but your input has been really helpful so many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you solved your client-sie problem.

As you are using express there is no need for `JSON.stringfy`, 
you can use `res.json(maps)`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I haven't yet solved the client-side problem but will certainly be working on it tonight. I think dataType in the .ajax wrapper may be pertinent.